# Multiply two lists in Racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am using Racket to multiply to list with the same length. So far I have tried:

```
(define (multiply-list a b)
  (if ([(empty? a) (empty)])
      else (cons(*car(a)car(b)))
      cdr(a) cdr(b)))
```

I am having trouble understanding the syntax of Racket. I want to update the list to it's `cdr`. but I cannot get it right `a` and `b` are the lists.

Comment: Is the question about "adding two lists" or about "updating a list to its cdr"?  Please be sure the question title matches what you're actually asking.  The syntax in your example is pretty mangled;  it might be more helpful to start with a tutorial in Racket, or the documentation.

Comment: Why not use a higher order function instead of doing the recursion yourself? Near as I can tell, `(map * a b)` does what you want. Also, racket is a prefix language - to call a function f with arguments x and y, you do (f x y), not f(x y)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you were aiming for something like this:

```
(define (multiply-list a b)
  (if (empty? a)
      empty
      (cons (* (car a) (car b))
            (multiply-list (cdr a) (cdr b)))))
```

Explanation:

- In Scheme, we have to be very, very careful where we put a pair of `()`. In your code, some parentheses are unnecessary and others are misplaced. A good IDE will help you put them in the right place
- For instance, the pair of `[]` surrounding the condition are wrong, and so is this: `(empty)` because `empty` is not a function, we surround something with `()` when we want to call it like a function
- And we don't call a function like this: `car(a)`. The correct way is: `(car a)`
- When we use `if`, the alternative part of the expression must not be preceded by `else`, maybe you're confusing an `if` expression with a `cond` expression.
- And last but not least: don't forget to call the recursion!

Comment: Like Jack said, really it should just be `(map * a b)`. :-D